# Laravel won't send response after a successful create of an account

Tags: php, laravel

I can save the data to the database just fine. And then I right after the creation I'll login that current user with the email. But it will always be sending a request. What might be the problem here?

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

private $loginProxy;


public function __construct(LoginProxy $loginProxy)
{
    $this->loginProxy = $loginProxy;
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

function apiRegisterUser(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'     => 'string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(array('code' => 406, 'error' => $validator->messages()), 406);
    } else {
        // Log::channel('abuse')->info('user');
        
        $user = User::create(['name'     => $request['name'],
                              'email'    => $request['email'],
                              'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
                              'referral_code' => str_random(10)
        ]);
        
        $user->updateLastRoute(1);
        $credentials = $this->loginProxy->attemptLogin($request['email'], $request['password']);

        return response()->json($this->successResponse(200, "Login successfull", $credentials), 200);
    }
}


protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: @KamleshPaul, What do you mean?

Comment: this is custom function you have created or laravel default auth function .?

Comment: Oh, it's the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `auth()->attempt()` function i m not sure about `loginProxy`
but `auth()->attempt()` this should work

```php
$credentials = [
    "email" => $request['email'],
    "password" => $request['password']
];

if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
    return response()->json($this->successResponse(200, "Login successfull", $credentials), 200);
}
```

Comment: How can I call the register method then inside the create method?

Comment: Tried it and it still the same it's always sending a request

Comment: What I'm thinking is register() method never got called when I created the user. Here in create function after a loginattempt you just return the $user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223672/discussion-between-kamlesh-paul-and-mark-andog).